# select coressponding next child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following html

```
<div id="test">
<p class="one"></p> <---first one----->
<p class="two"></p>
<p class="three"></p>
<p class="four"></p>
<p class="one"></p> <---second one---->
<p class="two"></p>
<p class="three"></p>
<p class="four"></p>
<p class="one"></p> <--- third one----->
<p class="two"></p>
<p class="three"></p>
<p class="four"></p>
</div>
```

Ok, now I'm at first `.one class` then I would like to select next `.one class` and again if I'm in second one then I would like to select next `.one class` from this. I think there is not `:next-child` something like this `.one:next-child` so how could I do?

---

**update**

@chopper answer is okay! but if it cannot find next one then it should select first `one`

Comment: Sorry, did not get what you meant by *at first `.one` class*.

Comment: in my ex- .one:next-child should now select next one class but there is no such pseudo selector

Comment: But what is next one class? You mean if your mouse pointer is in first `.one` item you want to style the next such item? I don't think CSS can/is designed to do that

Comment: Sorry mate, I don't know if it is just me. But I still don't understand the question fully. So better I leave it to the others :)

Comment: **but if it cannot find next one then it should select first one** that is just can be achieved by simple `if else` statements. :/

Comment: And jQuery also has a neat `.first()` function -> `$.first('.one')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the jQuery `.next()` selector:

```
var secondOne = firstOne.next('.one');
```

**EDIT**: @KevinB is right, the correct answer is

```
var secondOne = firstOne.nextAll('.one:first');
```

or

```
var secondOne = firstOne.nextAll('.one').first();
```

Comment: That is true. However the way he described it this is only possible via JS. Otherwise he could simply select all ones through `.one`

Comment: If this isn't the right answer, then I don't understand the question at all.

Comment: @chopper: Understand. That is what I was trying to highlight too. In pure CSS, that is not possible imo.

Comment: Yes, in CSS there is no notions of states ('I am at the first .one') like he described.

Comment: @chopper: I have removed my comment now that OP has tagged jQuery :)

Comment: @Harry: No worries :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are trying. if you want the next `.one` you can just use the sibling selector.

```
p.one ~ p.one ~ p.one{
    background-color: green;
}
```

[**Working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/5mhp9/)

For example, if you want the second `.one` then do like this:

```
p.one ~ p.one {
     /* apply styles */   /* selects all sibling elements */
}

p.one ~ p.one ~ p.one{           /* overriding css  styles */
     /* apply default styles */  /* selects all other sibling elements leaving the second element */ 
}
```

[**Working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/5mhp9/2/) (*on hover*)

Comment: But how to find the current one and style the next one?

Comment: @Harry CSS is used for just applying styles. if the OP wants to find the element then he/she must do it dynamically.

Comment: Precisely, I was just trying to highlight that. As I said for the below answer, don't get me wrong. I am not trying to be negative :)

Comment: @Harry not at all pal. you have the point and you have the right to argue :).